# CKEDITOR strips unexpectly my custom tag in HTML tables

Tags: javascript, drupal, ckeditor

For a customer, we had to develop a plugin that allows user to select a content reference from Drupal. This reference is inserted as token in a WYSIWYG field.

In order to be clearly identifiable in the rich text content, we implemented a custom tag as follow"`<customtag token="...">label</customtag>`" that displays the token as a highlighted box.

We use CKEditor 4.4.8.

The custom tag is correctly displayed when used directly in a "P" tag:

```
<p><customtag token="...">label</customtag></p>
```

But when we insert it in HTML table, it is stripped by CKEditor.

we get that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>label</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

Instead of:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><customtag token="...">label</customtag></td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

We declare the customtag as followed:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd['customtag'] = CKEDITOR.dtd;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$blockLimit['customtag'] = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline['customtag'] = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$nonEditable['customtag'] = true;
if (parseFloat(CKEDITOR.version) >= 4.1) {
  // Register allowed tag for advanced filtering.
  editor.filter.allow('customtag[!*]', 'customtag', true);
  CKEDITOR.dtd.$object['customtag'] = true;
}
```

I tried `CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'customtag[*]';` instead of `editor.filter.allow('customtag[!*]', 'customtag', true);`and to play with the allow rules but without any success.

What do we miss for the custom tag is accepted in table too?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured out what it missing.

In the DTD definition, I did not defines in which HTML tags the custom tag can be included.

Apparently, when the custom tag is declared as "inline", CKEDITOR configures by itself most of the block HTML tags like "p" or "div" but it does not it for tags like "td" or "li".

I had to do it in my code as follow:

CKEDITOR.dtd['td']['customtag'] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd['li']['customtag'] = 1;

After, my tag has been correctly taken into account.

At the end, my code looks like this:

```
   CKEDITOR.dtd['customtag'] = CKEDITOR.dtd;
   CKEDITOR.dtd.$blockLimit['customtag'] = 1;
   CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline['customtag'] = 1;
   CKEDITOR.dtd.$nonEditable['customtag'] = 1;

   CKEDITOR.dtd['td']['customtag'] = 1;
   CKEDITOR.dtd['li']['customtag'] = 1;

   if (parseFloat(CKEDITOR.version) >= 4.1) {
       // Register allowed tag for advanced filtering.
       editor.filter.allow('customtag[!*]', 'customtag', true);
       CKEDITOR.dtd.$object['customtag'] = 1;
   }
```

As you can notice, I also changed the boolean values by integers ones. I did it just to align the settings done through my code on what CKEditor does for the other HTML tags.